# Including my <Extension()> file in my Module.vb file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I include all my VB.NET extensions in any of my fileName.aspx code by using:

> <%@ Assembly Src="MyExtensions.vb" %>

How would I also include that same extensions-file in my MyModule.vb code?

Everything I try just says:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'myCode' is not a member of 'String'.

and none of my extensions are ever found.

All the code was written using only NotePad++. All the files are put in 1 single folder...and everything works as expected... EXCEPT "the usage of extensions that live in MyExtenstions.vb... when trying to be used inside MyModule.vb".

We could NEVER get permission (and money, and time) from the company that owns the site to "redo it all, correctly". We are really just looking for a simple solution like:

> Just put "Imports MyExtension.vb" near the top of MyModule.vb

We don't have (and never have) a *.vbproj file. We tried creating a APP_CODE folder and putting our MyExtensions.vb file in there... but when the main page is loaded... it never sees MyExtensions.vb. (I'm not sure how that could ever work.)

Or maybe that's just impossible.

Things I do **NOT** want to do:

- Upgrade to a newer technology than ASP.NET/VB.NET.
- Convince the company to let us rewrite their entire site.
- Charge the customer $50,000 more than we promised.
- Buy/install/use Visual Studio on every machine we use. (That's why we just us notepad instead.)
- Restructure the entire site's folder layout. (Breaking links that have been in certain/correct folders for 15+ years.)
- We've never executed "compile". The beauty of ASP.NET is it automatically compiles when the page loads.

The site works 100% flawlessly. I just wanted a quick/simple "**what is the syntax for including my MyExtensions.vb file... inside MyModule.vb file**" (Like it works for all of our other *.aspx files.)

Comment: `<%@ Assembly Src="MyExtensions.vb" %>` <-- this doesn't actually "Include" the file - instead it compiles it at runtime and then links/references it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/d864zc1k(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: _"How would I also include that same extensions-file in my MyModule.vb code?"_ - If this is an "ASP.NET Website" project (i.e. without a `.vbproj` file) then move `MyModule.vb` into your `App_Code` _magic folder_ and then everything should-just-work (and you won't need `<%@ Assembly Src="MyExtensions.vb" %>` anymore, so you should remove it from all files), otherwise if this is a "real" ASP.NET Web Application project (with a `.vbproj`) then you can put the `.vb` files anywhere, just make sure their Build Action is "Compile" (and then also remove the `<%@ Assembly Src=...%>` part too).

Comment: Thousands of companies still use/want browser-based ASP.NET code... and we can't say "no thanks" to 95% of our company's income stream... because you like "newer technologies" instead.

Comment: You are aware that VB.NET and WebForms are EOLd, right? What's your plan for transitioning to .NET 6 or later?

Comment: Does anyone know what/where is "our magic folder"? This ASP.NET code has never needed/used a .vbproj file... nor any "build action = compile". It just instantly works as soon as it's placed online. That's why all our customers love it!

Comment: "magic folder" is a term-of-art and refers to the `App_*` directories added in ASP.NET 2.0 like `App_Code`, `App_Themes`, `App_Browsers`, and others: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/t990ks23(v=vs.100) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ex526337(v=vs.100)#application-folders

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a web applcation, but a asp.net site?

Then you can freely add code modules to the project, but you have to put them in the App_code folder.

You also notice that the add module is missing. (its not if you creating a asp.net web site application).

So, you can right click on the app_code folder, and choose add.

eg this:

[image]

(you can also of course choose add new item, and select class from above.

But we DON'T want a class, but a good old happy module.

So, just name the module as module2 or whatever.

And then you have this:

[image]

But, it WILL template out a class, like this:

[image]

so, just change above to this:

[image]

Now, if for some REALLY strange reason you don't have a app_code folder?

Well, you should. but, you can add one:

Right click on top project name, and this:

[image]

Now, if app_code already exists then of course you not offered the option to create.

When using a asp.net web site "application" (which you are not), then you not limited to putting class and modules into app_code.

But, for asp.net web site, then if you try to add a class outside of app_code, then you should get/see this message:

[image]

So, it actually rather difficult to mess this up.

Once you do above? Then like good old VB6, VBA, or vb.net?

You don't need to add some reference to each page - such general subs and functions are by default global to the applcation, and all code modules, all classes, and each web page should have free use of any public sub or function placed into that module.

They are somewhat similar to what we call a c# static class, but in fact are actually nicer, and you don't have to prefix each routine with the module or class name.

However, you CAN prefix subs/functions by module1, or 2 name etc, since it possible to drop in sub or function names into multiple code modules with the same name. If you do that, then you should get a compile error warning you.

so you might say have to use

```
Call Module2.MySubName()
```

if you have two Public MySubNames in two different modules.

Also, DO REALLY avoid using global variables scoped at the module level. (they can mess up, and be shared between web users). Thankfully, since asp is state-less, then scoping global variables does not make a whole lot of sense anyway.

So, you don't have to do anything more then dump your code modules and even classes into that app code folder. Once done, they they just work, and you should not have to do anything further.

So now you can drop in code into that module. Including any extensions.

In other code such as code behind in a web page then a standard imports at top of module as

Imports module1.myPublicExtenstion

Should work like any code that uses extensions

Comment: Wow. I have to do all that? I don't use MS Studio at all. Ever. (Just NotePad++) It's just a collection of individual files... that worked flawlessly for 15 years... until I tried to do 1 simple thing: "Include another file inside my *.vb file". Then it becomes a month-long nightmare of "you have to fix 20 other things (even if you don't want to and can't get permission from the site's owner)". How can I fix this WITHOUT buying/installing Visual Studio. We never use it, and don't want to start now.